# Mostrar tabla padre con su relacion en blade laravel

Tags: laravel, relaciones, blade

tengo varios dias con este problema, lo dejo de lado y sigo con otro asunto y vuelvo a el con mente fresca pero nada que lo resuelvo.
Tengo una tabla llamada Clientes

```
    class Cliente extends Model
{
   public function comision()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Comision::class);
    }
}
```

La cual tiene una relacion de uno a uno con otra tabla llamada Comision.

```
class Comision extends Model
{
 public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
    }
}
```

Logre hacer la consulta para el index de modo que me muestre todos los registros de clientes con sus comisiones respectivamente

```
class ClienteController extends AppBaseController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $clientes = Cliente::with('comision')->get();
            dd($clientes);
    
          
            return view('clientes.index',compact('clientes'));
    
        }
}
```

[image: dd de la variable clientes]
[image: dd donde se muestra la relacion con comision]

Pero no logro mostrarlo en la plantilla blade, asi lo intento mostrar

```
@foreach($clientes as $cliente)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $cliente->DNINIF }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cliente->nombres }}</td>

            <td>{{ $cliente->apellidos }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cliente->tipo_persona }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cliente->telefono }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cliente->user_id }}</td>
                {{$cliente->comision->id}}
      @endforeach
```

Pero el error casi siempre es:
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Por favor agradecere cualquier guia que me puedan dar, lo unico que quiero es mostrar una tabla con los clientes y sus comisiones relacionadas, por ejemplo:

[image: ejemplo]

Asi esta mi base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente haya algún Cliente que no tenga una comisión relacionada.

Comment: BetaM publique como esta mi base de datos, porloscerros, en este caso cada  cliente tiene una comision, pero existiran casos en el futuro de clientes sin comisiones eso afecta en algo?

Comment: Entonces pensando mejor en esto seria mejor mostrar la información en el index de comisión, como siempre habra una comision asociada a un cliente, bueno de verdad muchas gracias y disculpen la perdida de tiempo aunque me aclararon mucho este tema

Comment: En tu vista blade cuando vayas a imprimir el ID de comisión coloca una @ antes es decir `{{ @$cliente->comision->id }}` si al hacer esto no te arroja un error, efectivamente es como dice @porloscerros-Ψ hay uno de esos items que no tiene comisión y estas creyendo que si. Además, es buena practica colocar algo de validación (puede ser una operación ternaria) para evitar que en el futuro no se rompa el sistema por no tener comisión, que puede llegarse a dar en algún momento.

Comment: y qué sale poniendo en blade (dentro del foreach) `dd($cliente->comision)`?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, en realidad estaba viendolo de la manera incorrecto y ahora obtengo los clientes  en cada comision